# Python array.tostring - Explanation for the byte representation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know that array.tostring gives the array of machine values. But I am trying to figure out how they are represented.

e.g

```
>>> a = array('l', [2])
>>> a.tostring()
'\x02\x00\x00\x00'
```

Here, I know that 'l' means each index will be min of 4 bytes and that's why we have 4 bytes in the tostring representation. But why is the Most significant bit populated with `\x02`. Shouldn't it be `'\x00\x00\x00\x02`'?

```
>>> a = array('l', [50,3])
>>> a.tostring()
'2\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00'
```

Here I am guessing the 2 in the beginning is because 50 is the ASCII value of 2, then why don't we have the corresponding char for ASCII value of 3 which is Ctrl-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why is the Most significant bit populated with `\x02`. Shouldn't it be `'\x00\x00\x00\x02'`?

The `\x02` in `'\x02\x00\x00\x00'` is not the most significant byte. I guess you are confused by trying to read it as a hexadecimal number where the most significant digit is on the left. This is not how the string representation of an `array` returned by `array.tostring()` works. Bytes of the represented value are put together in a string left-to-right in the order from least significant to most significant. Just consider the array as a list of bytes, and the first (or, rather, 0th) byte is on the left, as is usual in regular python lists.

> why don't we have the corresponding char for ASCII value of 3 which is Ctrl-C?

Do you have any example where python represents the character behind <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> as `Ctrl-C` or similar? Since the ASCII code 3 corresponds to an unprintable character and it has no corresponding escape sequence, hence it is represented through its hex code.